# How to change X location axis for particle system?

Tags: particles, axis

The carrots aren't properly placed to the ground. These carrots were created via particle system.

I want to rotate my particle system X location axis 90 degrees.
Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a rule to give the proper orientation:

The particle object is considered along its **Y axis** and this is the axis that will give you the **Z** (say Z for now, but see below) on the mesh the particles are.

So if you want the carrots to be up (Z), you'll need to change them in edit mode so that what will be Z as particles is Y for the carrot mesh.

[image]

On the image above, all particles are well oriented, but the monkey that is used as particle object is oriented along Y, with no rotation.

Once you have this rule in mind, you now can play a bit with the particle orientation options:

[image]

As shown above, the orientation options are accessible if you check *'advanced'* on a hair particle system.

The main option is *'orientation axis'* (10 possibilities). Each of them is to indicate in which direction of the *emitter* the Y axis of the particle will be.

For instance, *'normal'* is to say the Y will be along the normal of the emitter faces. *'Global X'* is to say Y will be along X world axis, whatever the emitter orientation is. *'Object Z'* is to say Y will stay along Z of the emitter even if it is rotated.

I let you experiment about the other options.

Now, as said previously, you need to orientate appropriately you model in edit mode:

[image]

In the image above,

- On the left, Suzan oriented as usual: but it's top is along Z
- On the right, Suzan rotated in edit mode so that its top is along Y (Y is the axis we want)

Also, the particles will be emitted from the object origin. So eventually, you'll need (still in edit mode) to adjust the geometry to that the origin is placed conveniently to your needs.

Other options that may interest you:

[image]

- Randomize is to random above the Y axis (so randomly rotating using X or Z axis too)
- Phase is to give an initial orientation around the Y axis
- Randomize phase is to random around the phase
- Scale and scale randomness is to adjust the scale and to give randomness to it (so that all carrots are not exactly the same)

Comment: Thank you kindly, very appreciated @lemon

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is just to go into edit mode on your carrots and rotate them until they look correct on your particle system.

Comment: It works, but I'd like to know the other ways

Comment: Are you serious, one by one? I mean you would do the rotation of each object if you had a scene of 1 million carrots?, what an efficient method...

Comment: @Blender Blackened your clearly mistaken. His particle system instantiates a collection of 3 carrots as you can see. You would only need to rotate those 3 carrots, and the rest would change. But lemon's answer is much more efficient and clean

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if my system of particles had 100 objects I would have to rotate 100 objects, the point is that you can make a script that rotates the objects, I have no practice with the particle system but I do not think it is difficult to do so I'm actually trying

Comment: I wouldn't spend time doing that unless you want to get better at python, because @lemon 's answer is much easier

Comment: @user58715 Even if I had 100 objects I wouldn't do it in python, I would simply select all, rotate with pivot point "Individual Origins" and then apply rotation.