# how to use a plan to bisect an object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a character where the hair particles of the back of the head penetrate the head surface and can be seen from the mouth. The picture shows a very simplified model of my issue.

I would like to keep the part of the hair that exists out of the head and delete the rest of it or at least delete the part that appears when you look inside the mouth (if it's open).

I tried the Boolean modifier but they don't work (I think because the head is a plan and has no volume). What else can I try?

[image]

Comment: Hair object position from the emitter surface is relative to its origin. That mean you can keep it outside modifying the origin point position. For more detail see for instance: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147610/how-to-change-x-location-axis-for-particular-system/147618#147618

Comment: It seems that I forgot to mention that they are no longer particles as I already converted them to mesh.  Sorry :)

Comment: Now,  it's all about dealing with meshes only.

Comment: About the boolean cut, have you tried to convert the head to convex hull (you said this is a plane not a volume).

Comment: @lemon No, I didn't. I'll try this soon and I'll get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: @lemon I'm not sure if I didn't the right way. I went to edit mode and selected all the vertices. From Mesh menu, I selected Convex Hull. This destroyed the "shape" of the head. I tried it with the hair as well destroyed it too. I created it from the default cube and what I meant by plane is that the walls that the head is made of are very thin (like what the picture shows).

Comment: Difficult to do it with another mesh to show you. That could work or not depending on the geometry and boolean operation. But convex hull is for the head only in the idea.

Comment: @lemon Thank you so much lemon for your assistance. That's really appreciated. I know I ask hard questions. It's just because I'm too curious :) I'll do it manually. I'll go to edit mode (for the hair) and zoom inside the mouth and try to get rid of  the extra faces of hair.

Comment: What you can try is to make a sphere that is more or less deformed to fit your needs and use it for boolean operation on the hair. The guess is is the sphere is more regular, so it should work better with the modifier.

Comment: A sphere is a good idea. It'll make the process easier. Thanks again :)