# Rendering a plane plane of grass, proper particle settings, and scaling

Tags: modeling, particles, scale

I have built out this plane of grass from this tutorial:

Create Realistic Grass in Blender 2.8 in 15 minutes
CG Geek - YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GAm-7_3N6g

Here is a screen shot of my grass plane:
[image: Here is a screen shot of my grass plane]

I suspect that my grass plane has some settings that are off...
Here is a screen shot of my particle settings:
[image: Blender screen shot]

My goal is to create a grass plane that I can then put warehouse type buildings on in order to create a layout of a production facility.

Did I set up this plane correctly?

Is the Emission>Number:Value to high?

Can I set this up so that I can just tile these planes as necessary to accommodate the size I need as I build?

This is my first posting here so please forgive any ignorance on my part.

Please let me know if there is any information I left out that is needed to analyze this.

Thanks.

As always,

Bice

Comment: I'm flagging this question as "opinion-based", because this question has an opinion of the model, not something to actually fix.

Comment: Can that help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147610/how-to-change-x-location-axis-for-particular-system/147618#147618

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27, if I see well, the grass is flat on the above images and that's the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The plane looks fine.

You can reduce the number of grass particles by going to *Children* and switching from *None* to *Interpolated* and then lowering the number of particles as much as you like.

You can also duplicate it several times and render the grass only on the last render.