# Randomize particle rotation on only one axis

Tags: particles

Is there any way to randomly rotate particles in hair particle system? I'm trying to create foliage, and I'd like to rotate each plant by a random amount, but only on one axis. If there's a better solution to distribute plants, I'm open to that too.

Answer (score 3):

Enable *"advanced"*.

Enable *"rotation"*.

Choose the axis you want to be up (Y of the model will be along the choosen axis).

And *"randomize"* the phase.

[image]

Comment: For some reason when I do this it randomizes rotation along every axis, totally disregarding the Orientation Axis setting.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @glen_candle, is that more detailed answer a solution for what you need? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147610/how-to-change-x-location-axis-for-particle-system/147618#147618