# How can I place multiple objects on the mesh?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make similar shoes and I don't know how to make those extruding objects on the shoe strap/ on its sides (I've thought of particles, but my output is faaaaar from what I want, I don't know how to set the orientation axis so the placement is not off like in my blend file..)

[image: shoes reference]

my blend file is here:

[image]

Comment: For instance: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147610/how-to-change-x-location-axis-for-particular-system/147618#147618 But as the shoe has few elements, I think placing them manually can be easier (or object scatter addon).

Comment: thank you! is is very well explained. also, thank you for the advice of using object scatter, i will look into that, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Face snapping for this.

1. Enable *Face snapping > Median* (to snap with origin point)
2. Check ✓ *Allow Rotation to Target* (to match face orientation)
3. Position the rivets

[image]

Comment: i've retried it but i have a little problem(?). a lot of the cone's surface goes underneath the monkey's head. do i have to set something apart from snapping with median and allowing rotation to target ?

Comment: Hello :). All settings you need are described in the answer. But if it doesn't work, feel free to ask a new question with screenshots and perhaps a shared .blend :).

Comment: hi, here is a video i did while trying snapping objects to the plane: https://streamable.com/xms204
and a screenshot with the plane in edit mode (to see the faces) 
https://imgur.com/a/cjcZaFE

Comment: Hey :). This is because the origin in my example is at the base, the origin in your example is at the top :). Move the origin, and it will work.

Comment: aaa, cone's origin ? object-> set origin -> origin to geometry. like so ?

Comment: Well, you don't want to set the origin to geometry. You need to position it at the base of the cone :). Post a full new question and I'll add some gifs and explanations.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207007/how-can-you-move-the-origin-at-the-base-of-object thank you very much! i hope i don't spam