# How can you move the origin at the base of object?

Tags: origin

How can you move the origin at the base of object and not set the origin to geometry ?

(A follow-up question to this one: [How can I place multiple objects on the mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/206906/78972))

[image]

Comment: there's no automatic way to do it, select the base in Edit mode, then shift S > 3D Cursor to Selected, then back to Object mode, right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor. Or enable the Affect Only Origin option in the Options panel on the top right of your 3D view and move the origin wherever you want

Comment: thank you for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object Transform Origin to Geometry Floor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79654/object-transform-origin-to-geometry-floor)  also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just answering based on Moonboots's comment, because I promised the OP a gif :)

1. Select the base vertices
2. I *Edit mode* go *Mesh > Snap > Cursor to selected*
3. In *Object mode* go *Object > Set Origin > to 3D cursor*

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help! you really made my day

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :).