# Tree penetrating through terrain (geometry node)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying out geometry nodes to populate trees on my terrain, but the trees are penetrating through the terrain. I've been searching for a couple of days on why this is happening, but I can't seem to get the answer.

Please advise on how to fix this.

[image: Mesh]

[image: Geometry Node]

Comment: Where is the origin located on the base tree mesh? Is it in the center? Try moving it to the base of the tree.

Comment: or add a transform node between the object info and the instance on points node, and tweak the translation part

Comment: The origin was located at the center of the mesh, moving the origin to the base of the tree did the trick :) can't believe it was this easy. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Posting this in any case people don't know how to move the origin to the base of a mesh

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207007/how-can-you-move-the-origin-at-the-base-of-object