# Particles rotation not working correct

Tags: particles, hair

I can't get correct orientation with attached to the hair object.

The arrows should look in different directions (like on picture 2), but I have them like hair (picture 1)

In *Particle Properties > Rotation > Orientation Axis* set the *Normal* or *Normal-tangent*, should solve this problem, but did not.

[image: Particles rotation result]

[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: ok i attached it

Comment: Rotate Arrow in X -90 and Apply Rotation (Ctrl+A). In general - Object for particles should be in positive Y direction ... I would also expect positive Z, so don't ask me why :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change X location axis for particle system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147610/how-to-change-x-location-axis-for-particle-system)

Comment: ok thanks, I wonder how I was supposed to guess myself about Y..

Comment: Sure it is unintuitive. When I cant get rotation with tool setup I go to edit mode to rotate there, stop to fight with a system :) I voted to close your question - it is Duplication of mentioned link ... but I retract that since it took me an ages to find this one duplication ... problem asked milion times here ... Grrr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your arrow.
Tap on Tab to go to edit mode.

Tap A to select all.

Tap R X -90 to rotate.

Done.